# How to put Japanese Character in XSL-FO Using Apache FOP?

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have designed a Template in XSL-FO using XF Designer . The Template contains Few Tags where the Value comes from Database. On Java side we have used Apache FOP to convert the Template with values into PDF file and render the Result .

The templates works Fine when the Tags fetches the English values but when the Character in the database is Japanese it renders "????????" instead of the actual character

I have used Encoding as "UTF-8" and for that particular Tag block i have mentioned the Font-Family as "MS Gothic" or "Arial Unicode MS" both , But nothing works out .

The File could contain both the English Values and Japasese Values and we need all of them to be displayed as it is onto PDF file

Could anybody please help me on this , How can i do this ???

Thanks in Advance